# I delteted my Target at XCode

Tags: xcode, target, iphone

Hy!

I undeliberate my Target at XCode (iPhone App) & now when I want to create a new Target
and want to start it, it doesn't 'refer' to my App...

How do I set up this Target, that the target know's that it should run my App..!?
(Also my .app file is lost^^)

Many thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just drag and drop any component you had on you app.

1. Every .m file you had on your project in "Compile sources"
2. Every framework and library linked to you project in "Link Binary with Libraries"
3. Every image, info.plist, bundle, xib on you project in "Copy Bundle Resources"

That's it!

[image]

Comment: I did that.. and all works now, EXCEPT i got an saveerror when I want to save one of my ManagedObjects... =(

Do I drag&drop anything from my xdatamodel to the target?! (if yes, where?)